How to invoke a synchronous java method from a python coroutine?
I have a Python coroutine as written below. I've hit a problem that the coroutine invokes a synchronous java method.
from functools import wraps
from py4j.java_gateway import JavaGateway


def authorization(func):
    @wraps(func)
    async def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        # Processing code
        gateway = JavaGateway()
        gateway_entry_point = gateway.entry_point
        jwt_authentication = gateway_entry_point.getData().validate(token)
        
        
        return await func(jwt_authentication.getInfo(), *args, **kwargs)

    return decorated

Instantiating JavaGateway and using it for gateway_entry_point.getData().validate(token) are sync calls. How do I do the same asynchronously?
